# MS-SQL stored procedure to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, string, delimiter

can anybody help me to write the following MS-SQL sp to MySQL sp,

use of this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InputWork 
    @_DelimitedString nvarchar(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @_DataRow nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @_DescriptionOfWorkDone nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @_TemporaryStorage nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @_QTY int
    DECLARE @_Total int
    DECLARE @_CurrentField int

    WHILE CHARINDEX(';', @_DelimitedString) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @_DataRow = CAST(SUBSTRING(@_DelimitedString, 0, CHARINDEX(';', @_DelimitedString)) AS nvarchar(MAX))
        SET @_CurrentField = 1
        WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @_DataRow) > 0
            BEGIN
            SET @_TemporaryStorage = CAST(SUBSTRING(@_DataRow, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @_DataRow)) AS nvarchar(MAX))
            IF @_CurrentField = 1
                SET @_QTY = CAST(@_TemporaryStorage AS int)
                    IF @_CurrentField = 2
            SET @_DescriptionOfWorkDone = @_TemporaryStorage
                    IF @_CurrentField = 3
                    SET @_Total = CAST(@_TemporaryStorage AS int)           
            SET @_DataRow = SUBSTRING(@_DataRow, CHARINDEX(',', @_DataRow) + 1, LEN(@_DataRow))
            SET @_CurrentField = @_CurrentField + 1
        END
        INSERT INTO tblWorkDone (QTY, DescriptionOfWorkDone, Total) VALUES (@_QTY, @_DescriptionOfWorkDone, @_Total)
        SET @_DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(@_DelimitedString, CHARINDEX(';', @_DelimitedString) + 1, LEN(@_DelimitedString))
        END 
END
```

Comment: What error do you get and what have you tried ?

Comment: @RaviSingh  What I am doing is passing a string to SP like (a, test,100.00, 1;b,test1,150.00, c;) ie fields separated by coma and value set by separated by semicolon, I would like SP to loop thru valueset and then thru fields then insert into table. I haven't tried this in Mysql. I got this sp from a site [link]http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?516496-Inserting-datagrid-view-data-to-sql-database[/link]

Comment: This should work in mysql with changes : 1) Change `charindex` to `instr()`. 2) Use `IF..THEN` instead of `IF`.

Comment: @RaviSingh what about while loop, in mysql its like while .....do .... end while; and  nvarchar to **text** or **blob**???. will it work????

Comment: Yes, that one aswell.

Comment: @RaviSingh let me try and revert you :)

Comment: use `VARCHAR(n) CHARSET utf8` instead of `nvarchar`.That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the SP to Mysql

```
BEGIN
DECLARE _DataRow VARCHAR(21000);
 DECLARE _DescriptionOfWorkDone VARCHAR(21000);
DECLARE _TemporaryStorage VARCHAR(21000) ;
DECLARE _QTY int;
DECLARE _Total int;
DECLARE _CurrentField int;

WHILE INSTR(_DelimitedString, ';') >0 DO

    SET _DataRow = CAST(SUBSTRING(_DelimitedString, 1, INSTR(_DelimitedString,';' )) AS CHAR);
    SET _CurrentField = 1;
    WHILE INSTR(_DataRow,',' ) > 0 DO         
        SET _TemporaryStorage = CAST(SUBSTRING(_DataRow, 1, INSTR(_DataRow,',' )-1) AS CHAR);
        IF _CurrentField = 1 then
            SET _QTY = CAST(_TemporaryStorage AS UNSIGNED);
                end if;
                      IF _CurrentField = 2 then
        SET _DescriptionOfWorkDone = _TemporaryStorage;
                end if;
                      IF _CurrentField = 3 then
                SET _Total = CAST(_TemporaryStorage AS UNSIGNED)    ;   
                     end if;    

        SET _DataRow = SUBSTRING(_DataRow, INSTR( _DataRow,',') + 1, LENGTH(_DataRow));
        SET _CurrentField = _CurrentField + 1;
         END while;

    INSERT INTO tblWorkDone (QTY, DescriptionOfWorkDone, Total) VALUES (_QTY, _DescriptionOfWorkDone, _Total);
    SET _DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(_DelimitedString, INSTR(_DelimitedString,';' ) + 1, LENGTH(_DelimitedString));

   END WHILE;END
```

Data inserted

```
CALL `sp_InputWork`('1,TEST,100,;2,TEST1,200,;3,TEST3,300,;')
```

**Successfully looped and inserted to Mysql Table**

Comment: Sorry if I read this incorrectly, but this is not a solution is it? (Assuming you dont' consider "null to all fields" correct). If so: please don't post it as an answer, but update your question: this is not your typical forum, this is a Q&A site, and the 'your answer' box is voor actual answers :)

Comment: @Nanne finally I got it worked and Posted correct Answer, My apologies for updating my question as answer